# Is it possible for me to open a native application (Example Microsoft Whiteboard) of windows in my c# windows form application?

Tags: c#

Below is an example of how I open Zoom and Teams

```cs
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string user = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.UserName.ToString();
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/Users/" + user + "/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Teams/current/Teams.exe");
}

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string user = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.UserName.ToString();
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/Users/" + user + "/AppData/Roaming/Zoom/bin/Zoom.exe");
}
```

Note: Unlike Zoom and Teams that when installed they create a folder where we find all the installation supplements, but Whiteboard does not have any folder against these supplements. That's why it's very difficult to open it from my application in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Whiteboard is a store app.
Here's a Post about [How to open Microsoft Store apps from Command Prompt?](https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/how-to-open-microsoft-store-apps-from-command-prompt/)

You can find these apps here:
`shell:AppsFolder`

From CMD you can start it with

`explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.Whiteboard_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Whiteboard`

From code it can be started this way:

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.Whiteboard_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Whiteboard");
```

Another example can be found here:
https://notepad.onghu.com/2020/launch-win10-app-from-cmdline/

Comment: Hello dear Markus, I've been looking at the shared link, and right now I'm trying to implement it, it seems I'm on the right track.
Regardless of the result, I will speak in a few minutes.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi Markus, thank you very much for your contribution.
Luckily I managed to solve it with your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

From the code it seems like you just want to start the process, not run it directly on your winform app. By default, applications downloaded from Microsoft Store are stored in **C:/Program Files/WindowsApps**.